# Setting object into a table row with JSTL

Tags: javascript, html, jstl

I'm a beginner in JSTL, Javascript and web programming but am reasonably comfortable with Java.

I am building a web application that queries an SQL database, puts the data into a list, and puts that list into a table on a web page with each element of the list having it's own row. I've gotten that part working great:

```
<tbody>
        <c:forEach var="i" items="${cardList}" >                        
            <tr>
                <td>${i.installDate}</td>
                <td>${i.removeDate}</td>
                <td>${i.age}</td>
            </tr>       
        </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

What I'm trying to do now is make it so that when the user clicks on the row it sends all the data (The row only shows 25% of the full data that is stored in the Java bean) from that row to another web page that displays all 100%.

I am having difficulty conceptually understanding how to make this work - I know I need to use Javascript for the row clicking functionality, but how do I pass the Bean and/or full information to the next page?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you have to display the data of the clicked row to another page

If it is so on click you have to navigate to some servlet with the rows unique id field say /someservlet?id=someid

Then in that servlet get the id and fetch the corresponding data from database using bean and give that data to the page you wished to display the content

Answer (score 2):

I think it will do the magic

```
/servletname?id=id
```

Answer (score 0):

create your new page with link like /card/{id} in Java and use Javascript to redirect to that link:

```
link ="/card/";
window.location = link+id;
```

if your card has ID field in SQL database, id = your card's ID

if your card doesn't have any identified field, you can use index of item in the list, instead. Then id = index of card in the list you received by query